# How to make an output in the respective element when you click through array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to make Active if the Countries I check is Inactive. But I didnt know how, here's my code.

PS: I use mobile phone for now, so that Snippet is not avail. For those who extract my code through Snippet is much appreciated.

This is the example, because the only problem is how to make any function if you click the respective element or div. Like for example, if I check the checkbox in 2nd div, there's something happen in 2nd div only. Then if I didn't check the others div, it nothing happens or affected.

```js
const Countries = ["Philippines", "New York", "Singapore"];

function createList() {
  const liTag = $('.Handler');
  for (let i = 0; i < Countries.length; i++) {
    const List = `
      <ul id="CountryList">
       <li>
          <div class="NameOfCountry">
            <input type="checkbox" class="Check">
            <p class="CountryName">Hello</p>
            <p class="InActive">Inactive</p>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>   
    `;
    
    var elem = $(List);
    elem.find('.CountryName').html(Countries[i]);
    elem.find('.Check').change(function() {
      //Create a code that if the checkbox is Check, the word inactive makes Active on Respective Element. 
    })
    liTag.append(elem);
  }
}
createList();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  background: #40fff5;
}

.Handler {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

.NameOfCountry {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 6px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.CountryName {
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.InActive {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: red;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Handler"></div>
```

Comment: hard to understand your question...the details of the question, what is it that you expect your code to do, what is doing instead?

Comment: Hard to understand my question or hard understand my code?

Comment: @ChrisG my only problem is How to make the word Inactive as Active after you check the checkbox on every element. Please see the Code Snippet. There's a checkbox and Inactive in every Country. If you click the checkbox like for example in Philippines, the Inactive make Active

Comment: All answers are correct and thank you for your cooperation. But I checked the answer made by @ChrisG because this is the closest answer to my project. Toggle Classlist if the checkbox is check or not

Comment: glad to be of help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a few things
Added the `status` class to your

tag
added a few things to your `.change` function to toggle between 'Active' and 'Inactive' and change the background color based on the checkbox state.

```js
const Countries = ["Philippines", "New York", "Singapore"];

function createList() {
  const liTag = $('.Handler');
  for (let i = 0; i < Countries.length; i++) {
    const List = `
          <ul id="CountryList">
            <li>
              <div class="NameOfCountry">
                <input type="checkbox" class="Check">
                <p class="CountryName">${Countries[i]}</p>
                <p class="Status Inactive">Inactive</p>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        `;

    var elem = $(List);
    elem.find('.Check').change(function() {
      const statusElem = $(this).closest('.NameOfCountry').find('.Status');
      statusElem.text($(this).prop('checked') ? 'Active' : 'Inactive');
      statusElem.toggleClass('Active Inactive');
    });
    liTag.append(elem);
  }
}

createList();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #40fff5;
}

.Handler {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

.NameOfCountry {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 6px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.CountryName {
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.Active {
  background: green;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.Inactive {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: red;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Handler"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your question correctly, your goal is to toggle the 'InActive' text to 'Active' based on the state of the checkbox within any given row.

To do this, you can use a single delegated event handler which accepts an Event object as an argument. You can determine which checkbox triggered the event from that Event and traverse the DOM to update its related `p` element.

Below is a working example. Note that I added some classes to the content to make identifying elements easier, and I also moved the HTML out of the JS in to the HTML to maintain a good Separation of Concerns.

```js
const createList = ($container, countryList) => {
  const countryHtmlTemplate = $('#country-list-item-template').html();

  countryList.forEach(country => {
    let listItem = countryHtmlTemplate.replace('{{Name}}', country);
    $countryContainer.append(listItem);
  });
  
  $container.on('change', ':checkbox', e => {
    $(e.target).closest('li').find('.state').text((i, t) => e.target.checked ? 'Active' : 'InActive');
  });
}

const $countryContainer = $('.handler');
const countries = ["Philippines", "New York", "Singapore"];
createList($countryContainer, countries);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  background: #40fff5;
}

.Handler {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

.NameOfCountry {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 6px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.CountryName {
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.InActive {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: red;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="handler"></div>

<template id="country-list-item-template">
  <ul id="CountryList">
    <li>
      <div class="NameOfCountry">
        <input type="checkbox" class="Check">
        <p class="CountryName">{{Name}}</p>
        <p class="state InActive">Inactive</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul> 
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const Countries = ["Philippines", "New York", "Singapore"];

function createList() {
  const liTag = $('.Handler');
  for (let i = 0; i < Countries.length; i++) {
    const List = `
      <ul id="CountryList">
       <li>
          <div class="NameOfCountry">
            <input type="checkbox" class="Check">
            <p class="CountryName">Hello</p>
            <p class="InActive">Inactive</p>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>   
    `;
    
    var elem = $(List);
    elem.find('.CountryName').html(Countries[i]);
    liTag.append(elem);
  }
}
createList();

document.querySelectorAll('.Check').forEach(check => {
  check.addEventListener('change', ({ target }) => {
    const { parentNode, checked } = target
    const inActiveElement = parentNode.querySelector('.InActive')
    inActiveElement.innerText = checked ? 'Active' : 'Inactive'
  })
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  background: #40fff5;
}

.Handler {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

.NameOfCountry {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 6px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.CountryName {
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.InActive {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: red;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Handler"></div>
```